# Regular expression in file path shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a list of folders for all clients in Documents, so in `~/Documents/clients/` folder the folders appear like that for example:

```
Angelina_Julie-client23456
Brad_Pitt-client34567
Tom_Hanks-client12345
```

and so on. Then I have the below script:

```
clientcode="client12345"
cdate=$(date +%F)
mydir="/home/userA/Documents/clients/$clientcode"_"$cdate/"
```

The problem is that `"/home/userA/Documents/$clientcode"_"$cdate/"` this path is not found cause there is client `firstname_lastname-` before the clientcode so the correct mydir in this case for example `/home/userA/Documents/Tom_Hanks-$clientcode"_"$cdate/` so as you can see `Tom_Hanks-` was added. So I wonder how I can make it automatically gets and includes the Firstname_Lastname- depending on the `$clientcode` since it's unique in the `~/Documents/clients/` folder, and add it to `mydir`?

Comment: Your example directories don't have any date in them.

Comment: You are planning to set `mydir` variable to: `/home/userA/Documents/clients/Tom_Hanks-client12345_2019-07-03/`.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using find:

```
clientcode="client12345"
cdate=$(date +%F)
mydir="$(find /home/userA/Documents/clients/ -name "*${clientcode}*" -type d)_$cdate"
```

This will find the directory whose name contains `clientcode` and append `_$cdate` to the end of it.

Note: this won't actually make changes to the directory name.  The directory name as it exists in `mydir` doesn't appear to actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

Given those dirs, `.../clients/*-"$clientcode"/` would expand to the matching directory names. Note that the asterisk is unquoted. (It's not a regular expression though, but a glob pattern.)

But you can't use a pattern in an expansion, so you'd need to work around it, with e.g. a loop:

```
mydir=
for d in ./clients/*-"$clientcode"/; do
    if [ "$mydir" ]; then
        echo "More than one matching directory!" >&2
    fi
    mydir=$d
done
if [ -z "$mydir" ]; then
    echo "No match!" >&2
fi
```

I'm not sure if the date is supposed to be part of the filename to be matched (so `./clients/*-"$clientcode"_*/`), or if you're going to append it and create a new one (`newdir="${mydir}_${date}"`).